# C++ clang UBsan suppression flag name

Tags: c++, clang++, ubsan

Running the `gzip.hpp` code from boost version 1.64 with clang's ubsan gives the following message:

```
path/to/boost/1_64_0/include/boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp:674:16: runtime error: implicit conversion from type 'int' of value 139 (32-bit, signed) to type 'char' changed the value to -117 (8-bit, signed)
    #0 0x7fed40b77bc2 in boost::iostreams::basic_gzip_compressor<std::allocator<char> >::basic_gzip_compressor(boost::iostreams::gzip_params const&, long)
```

I'd like to suppress this with with a suppression file. For other warnings this has worked:

```
 unsigned-integer-overflow:path/to/boost/*
```

In this case I would expect that this should work

```
implicit-integer-sign-change:/lfs/vlsi/tools/boost/*
```

but it gives at runtime

```
UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: failed to parse suppressions
```

What is the right name of this sanatizer flag?

See also: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html#runtime-suppressions

and from https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html#available-checks

> -fsanitize=implicit-integer-sign-change: Implicit conversion between integer types, if that changes the sign of the value. That is, if the
>   the original value was negative and the new value is positive (or
>   zero), or the original value was positive, and the new value is
>   negative. Issues caught by this sanitizer are not undefined behavior,
>   but are often unintentional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have been helped on the llvm cfe-dev  [mailing list](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2019-January/061054.html)

TLDR: The name of the warning type is not `implicit-integer-sign-change` but instead `implicit-integer-truncation` which can be suppressed as expected. The name of the error type can be found out using `export UBSAN_OPTIONS=report_error_type=1`.

Answer (score 0):

According to this very documentation you're reading you suppress UBSan messages using the following step :

> **Disabling Instrumentation**
>   ***with__attribute__((no_sanitize("undefined")))¶***
>
> You disable UBSan checks for particular functions
>   with `__attribute__((no_sanitize("undefined"))).` You can use all values
>   of -fsanitize= flag in this attribute, e.g. if your function
>   deliberately contains possible signed integer overflow, you can
>   use__attribute__((no_sanitize("signed-integer-overflow"))).
>
> This attribute may not be supported by other compilers, so consider
>   using it together with #ifdefined(**clang**).

So what you should do is: check the documentation in the same page for what you want to suppress and conjugate it with `use__attribute__((no_sanitize("here_goes_checks_you_want_to_suppress"))).` or `use__attribute__((no_sanitize("undefined"))).` to disable UBSan altogether.

Apart of that seems UBSan is throwing a SIGNED integer overflow and you're trying to suppress UNSIGNED integer overflow.

LINKS: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html

Comment: The `__attribute__` way is only one way to suppress UBsan messages. Runtime suppressions are the alternative I'd like to use, since I don't want to alter the boost library. As for the `unsigned-integer-overflow`: This is the flag I was able to use for a different boost warning.

Comment: Have you tried using `signed-integer-overflow:path/to/boost/1_64_0/include/boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp`?

Comment: I personally doubt very much you can suppress this specific error using anything other than `signed-integer-overflow` since that's clearly the issue UBSan is catching

Comment: I must disappoint you, `signed-integer-overflow` does get parsed but the `gzip.hpp` still gets reported.

Comment: The question is specifically about runtime UBSan suppressions.

Comment: Uhh, sorry, my bad then. Then you could try `-fsanitize=implicit-signed-integer-truncation `, if that solves the problem, I edit the answer, I'd that doesn't, then I'm out of options :(